# Qual a melhor forma de fazer uma análise descritiva de datas de nascimento no R?

Tags: r, data

Tenho em meu quadro de dados uma coluna de datas de nascimentos que estão no modelo inglês, mas não sei como analisar isso descritivamente nem que recursos usar do R.

Eu deveria usar um gráfico de barras ou um histograma? Como faria para o R entender que são datas?
Eu tentei me arriscar fazendo isso:

```
x = as.Date(rehab.1$Data.Nascimento)

hist(x, main = "Data de Nascimento", breaks = "years",axes = TRUE, xlab = "data", ylab = "Frequência Absoluta", col = "green")
```

Mas o que saiu não ficou legal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o tipo de dado de `rehab.1$Data.Nascimento`? Você pode mostrar um exemplo destes valores (i.e., `head(rehab.1$Data.Nascimento)`?)

Comment: head(rehab.1$Data.Nascimento)
[1] 1/10/1953 6/1/1941  4/11/1941 5/2/1946  6/18/1938 7/12/1941
376 Levels:  1/1/1924 1/10/1953 1/11/1924 1/11/1950 1/15/1923 1/16/1936 ... 9/8/1941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu código tem alguns problemas:

- A função `as.Date` assume que a data está no formato Y/m/d, e a sua data está no formato m/d/Y. Troque a primeira chamada para `x <- as.Date(rehab.1$Data.Nascimento, "%m/%d/%Y")`
- Qual a informação que você quer mostrar no seu histograma? Quantas pessoas nasceram em cada ano? Em cada mês? Dependendo do que você quiser, você irá usar métodos diferentes.

Por exemplo, para mostrar o número de nascimentos por ano, você pode usar o método que você usou (hist, com breaks = "years"), como no código abaixo.

```
randomDates <- function(N, st = "1/1/1920", et = "12/31/2015") {
    st <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date(st, "%m/%d/%Y"))
    et <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date(et, "%m/%d/%Y"))
    dt <- as.numeric(difftime(et, st, unit = "sec"))
    ev <- runif(N, 0, dt)
    st + ev
}
x <- randomDates(1000)
hist(x, freq = TRUE,
     breaks = "years", col = "green",
     xlab = "ano", "ylab" = "Frequencia",
     main = "Ano de nascimento")
```

Comment: Valeu Carlos, muito obrigado cara! :D